# Pause Jquery script on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseover, ticker, news-ticker

I use this little code snippet for a jquery news ticker:

```
var speed = 5;
var items, scroller = $('#scroller');
var width = 0;

scroller.children().each(function(){
    width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

scroller.css('width', width);

scroll();

function scroll(){
    items = scroller.children();
    var scrollWidth = items.eq(0).outerWidth();
    scroller.animate({'left' : 0 - scrollWidth}, scrollWidth * 100 / speed, 'linear', changeFirst);
}

function changeFirst(){
    scroller.append(items.eq(0).remove()).css('left', 0);
    scroll();
}
```

I try to pause the script when mouseover.

Using stop() function, it works but it loses speed every time I pass my mouse over.

I know their is something to do with width / distance / speed but I'm unable to correct it.

Here is the full script: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBayyz

Thank You.

Comment: Check my answer for a CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
    var speed = 5;
    var items, scroller = $('#scroller');
    var width = 0;
  
    scroller.children().each(function(){
        width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
    });
  
    scroller.css('width', width);
  
    scroll();
    
    function scroll(){
        items = scroller.children();
        var scrollWidth = items.eq(0).outerWidth();
        scroller.animate({'left' : (items.eq(0).offset().left - 39) - scrollWidth}, scrollWidth * 100 / speed, 'linear', changeFirst);
    }
  
    function changeFirst(){
        scroller.append(items.eq(0).remove()).css('left', 0);
        scroll();
    }
  $("#scroller").hover(function() {
  $(this).stop();
}, function() {scroll();});
});
```

```css
#scroller{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;line-height:30px;position:relative;}

#scroller li{float:left;height:30px;padding:0 0 0 10px;list-style-position:inside;}

#scrollerWrapper{width: 500px; height:30px;margin:30px;overflow:hidden;border:1px #333 solid;background:#F2F2F2;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<title>Horizontal scroller</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="scrollerWrapper">
  
  <ul id="scroller">

    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>

    <li> Maecenas sollicitudin, ante id ultrices consectetur.</li>

    <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. </li>

  </ul>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem was when you were restarting the scrolling you need to take into consideration how much has been scrolled already, like I've done here.

This should be what you're looking for,

Comment: Nice but it breaks a little bit how scrolling is done.

Comment: What do you mean it breaks how scrolling is done? I only tested it in Chrome but it seemed to work the way I thought it should.

Comment: Look at the scroll few seconds. It "jumps". I use Chrome too.

Comment: Alright that should have it fixed, it looks like when it starts it has an offset of 39, not 0. So I corrected for that to get rid of the jump.

Comment: Ok thank you. It still jumping after mouseover.I'll try to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using this plugin: http://tobia.github.io/Pause/

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need javascript. Most current browsers support CSS only animation, for the kind of task you have in hands.

```css
#scroller {
  display: inline-block;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  line-height:30px;
  -webkit-animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
  -moz-animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
  -o-animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
  animation: roll 10s infinite linear;
}

#scroller:hover {
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
  -moz-animation-play-state: paused;
  -o-animation-play-state: paused;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@-webkit-keyframes roll {
 from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
 to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-moz-keyframes roll {
 from { -moz-transform: translateX(100%); }
 to { -moz-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@-o-keyframes roll {
 from { -o-transform: translateX(100%); }
 to { -o-transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@keyframes roll {
 from { transform: translateX(100%); }
 to { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}


#scroller li {
  display: inline-block;
  height:30px;
  padding:0 0 0 10px;
  list-style-position:inside;
}

#scrollerWrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 500px;
  height:30px;
  margin:30px;
  overflow:hidden;
  border:1px #333 solid;
  background:#F2F2F2;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Horizontal scroller</title>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="scrollerWrapper">
  
  <ul id="scroller">

    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>

    <li> Maecenas sollicitudin, ante id ultrices consectetur.</li>

    <li>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient. </li>

  </ul>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice solution too. But I need old browser support. I keep this code for futur projects, thank you !